# Выводиться boolean вместо параметра в циры

Tags: php, mysql, sql, запрос, select

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(sumer) as total  FROM out"); 
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$values = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);//ошибка
echo $values['total'];
```

Он всё равно выводит `boolean` (выводит ошибку):

> "Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in ..."

Answer (score 1):

Что Вы этим хотели сказать?

> `$sql = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(sumer) as total  FROM out"); 
>   $result = mysql_query($sql);`

Ну и иногда полезно читать документацию

> Для запросов SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN и других запросов, возвращающих результат из нескольких рядов, mysql_query() возвращает дескриптор результата запроса (resource), или **FALSE в случае ошибки**.
>
> Для других типов SQL-запросов, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP и других, mysql_query() возвращает TRUE в случае успеха и **FALSE в случае ошибки**.

Текст ошибки можно получить, вызвав функцию `mysql_error()`

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(sumer) as total  FROM out"; 
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$values = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);//ошибка
echo $values['total'];
```

Вот так дожно работать. У вас лишний `mysql_query`